# Clarification regarding Pending Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

Say I have an application A that uses an intent to launch an application B's component. Then if I wrap that intent into a pending intent and pass it to an application C, does this mean that app C will launch app B's component, using app A's permissions?

Comment: Yes you are right but You missed the first part itself I guess. When you will pass an intent from A to B you need to use Pending Intent itself over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have the flow correctly described. Note that App B is not specifically involved in this flow. The `Intent` could point to a component in App A, B, C, D, E, etc. The only specific parties are:

- App C, which sends the `PendingIntent`, and
- App A, which created the `PendingIntent` and therefore is considered the actual originator of the request for security purposes